# PHP MySQL maxTime Query

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a routine that runs every couple of hours and records what backup jobs users have configured.  Each job creates an entry in a table and the number of entries could be anything from 0 to infinity (depends entirely on the number of jobs a user has).

In the example below, the user has three backup jobs configured currently, but the SQL query I'm using is pulling a backup from a data pull over a week ago.  I can't figure out how to tune my query so that I get only entries from the most recent timestamp without doing a LIMIT (I can't use LIMIT because I never know the number of entries that will appear):

```
SELECT BACKUP_SET_ID, BACKUP_SET_TYPE, Max(SNAPSHOT_TIME) maxTime
FROM TABLE_snapshots_backupsets
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='6000001'
GROUP BY BACKUP_SET_ID;
```

Output:

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+  
| BACKUP_SET_ID | BACKUP_SET_TYPE                  | maxTime             |  
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+  
| 1359127993672 | FILE                             | 2013-02-04 08:00:01 |  
| 1359145357475 | FILE                             | 2013-02-04 08:00:01 |  
| 1359145395067 | VMware Virtualization            | 2013-02-04 08:00:01 |  
| 1359145404910 | Microsoft Windows Virtualization | 2013-01-27 12:00:01 |  
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------------+  
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, in the case above, what I want is for the query to not pull the 'Microsoft Windows Virtualization' entry because the user no longer has that one configured as of the most recent data pull.  It should only be pulling entries with the most recent timestamp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the most recent entries that share the same timestamp, rearrange the logic a bit:

```
SELECT BACKUP_SET_ID, 
       BACKUP_SET_TYPE, 
       SNAPSHOT_TIME
FROM TABLE_snapshots_backupsets
WHERE SNAPSHOT_TIME = (SELECT Max(SNAPSHOT_TIME) 
                       FROM TABLE_snapshots_backupsets 
                       WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = '6000001')
;
```

Or if you need a "time range" solution, add an additional WHERE clause on snapshot_time

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='6000001' AND SNAPSHOT_TIME > CURTIME() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

For other date manipulation options: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I add that WHERE clause, I get no records returned at all....

Comment: Thank you!  OK - the rearranged query seemed to do the trick.  I had to add the ACCOUNT_ID to the first WHERE clause to get it to return only entries for that account:  `SELECT BACKUP_SET_ID, BACKUP_SET_TYPE, SNAPSHOT_TIME FROM TABLE_snapshots_backupsets WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='6000001' AND SNAPSHOT_TIME = (SELECT Max(SNAPSHOT_TIME) FROM TABLE_snapshots_backupsets WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='6000001') GROUP BY BACKUP_SET_ID;`

Comment: Oh yeah, the GROUP BY can be dropped now since there's no aggregate function in the main query anymore.  Editted the answer.